# I want to create a function in SQL but I am getting many errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create function in SQL Server in Management Studio for :

```
Input: 7589586586     Output:  (758) 958-6586
Input: 758ABC6586     Output: (758) 222-6586  
Input: 758ABC65       Output: Invalid Formats (like mobile keypad)
```

This is my SQL code which for which I'm getting many errors:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_bhagyashreed_phonenumber
    (@input VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @compare VARCHAR(30) = '';            
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
    DECLARE @varout VARCHAR(30) = '';
    DECLARE @val VARCHAR(30) = '';
    DECLARE @Phoutput VARCHAR(50) = '';
    DECLARE @var INT;

    SET @var = LEN(@input);

    IF @var <> 10 OR @input NOT REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$' THEN
        SET @Phoutput = 'Invalid Format';
    ELSE
        WHILE @cnt <= 10 
        BEGIN
            SET @compare = SUBSTRING(@input, @cnt, 1);

            IF @compare IN('a','b','c','2') 
            BEGIN
                SET @val=2;
            ELSE IF @compare IN('d', 'e', 'f', '3') 
            BEGIN
                SET @val=3;
            ELSE IF @compare IN('g', 'h', 'i', '4') 
            BEGIN
                SET @val = 4;
            ELSE IF @compare IN('j', 'k', 'l', '5') 
            BEGIN
                SET @val = 5;
            ELSE IF @compare IN('m', 'n', 'o', '6') 
            BEGIN
                SET @val = 6;
            ELSE IF @compare IN('p', 'q', 'r', 's', '7') 
            BEGIN
                SET @val = 7;
            ELSE IF @compare IN('t', 'u', 'v', '8') 
            BEGIN
                SET @val = 8;
            ELSE IF @compare IN('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '9') 
            BEGIN
                SET @val = 9;
            ELSE IF @compare = '1' 
            BEGIN
                SET @val = 1;
            ELSE IF @compare = '0' 
            BEGIN
                SET @val = 0;
        END 

        SET @varout = CONCAT(@varout,@val);
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END;

    SET @Phoutput = CONCAT('(',SUBSTRING(@varout,1,3),')',' ',SUBSTRING(@varout,4,3),'-',SUBSTRING(@varout,7,4));
END; IF;
RETURN Phoutput;
END$$
```

These are the errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_bhagyashreed_phonenumber, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near 'REGEXP'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_bhagyashreed_phonenumber, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_bhagyashreed_phonenumber, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>   .......

Comment: Localising the phone number output should be left to the GUI layer.

Comment: Instead of using REGEX, you may use LIKE example: `IF @var <> 10 OR @input NOT LIKE '^[[:alnum:]]+$' THEN`.

Comment: THANK YOU.IT HELPED.But what about concat? Can we use it in sql ?

Comment: `select @@version`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755(v=sql.120).aspx take a look at samples

Comment: WHAT can be used in place of CONCAT??

Comment: you can do it like this `@varout + @val`. we use `+` to concat in sqlserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your whole approach is far away from *sql thinking*. You do this procedural, but SQL - if ever possible - is best used *set based*.

Try this fully *ad-hoc* SQL

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,phoneString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('7589586586'),('758ABC6586'),('758ABC65');

WITH tenDigits AS (SELECT Nr FROM(VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS x(Nr))
,Splitted AS
(
    SELECT ID 
          ,Nr
          ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) IN('a','b','c','2') THEN '2'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) IN('d','e','f','3') THEN '3'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) IN('g','h','i','4') THEN '4'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) IN('j','k','l','5') THEN '5'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) IN('m','n','o','6') THEN '6'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) IN('p','q','r','s','7') THEN '7'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) IN('t','u','v','8') THEN '8'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) IN('w','x','y','z','9') THEN '9'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) ='1' THEN '1'
                WHEN SUBSTRING(phoneString,Nr,1) ='0' THEN '0'
                ELSE 'X'
            END AS Digit
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS JOIN tenDigits
)
,ReConcatenated AS
(
    SELECT s.ID
          ,'(' 
          + STUFF(STUFF(
           (SELECT x.Digit AS [*] 
            FROM Splitted AS x 
            WHERE s.ID=x.ID 
            ORDER BY Nr
            FOR XML PATH('')
           ),4,0,') '),9,0,'-') AS PhoneNumber
    FROM Splitted AS s
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('X',PhoneNumber)>0 THEN 'Invalid Format' ELSE PhoneNumber END AS Validated
FROM ReConcatenated
```

The result

```
ID  PhoneNumber     Validated
1   (758) 958-6586  (758) 958-6586
2   (758) 222-6586  (758) 222-6586
3   (758) 222-65XX  Invalid Format
```

### Short explanation

First I create a table variable to *mock-up* a test scenario. The first CTE `tenDigits` will create a derived table running from 1 to 10. The second CTE will return a derived table with the phonenumber's digits *one-by-one* and it will do the necessary replacements in the same go. The third CTE will reconcatenate the single digits to one piece of text. `STUFF` is used to push the `)` and the `-` into the right places. Finally the existence of an 'X' indicates an invalid number.

You might largen the first CTE to more than 10 digits and add and `X` if the `Nr` exceeds 10 to eliminate errors with to long numbers.

Comment: Nice approach.Thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple syntax errors in this and I'm not going through them individually.

Each `IF` must have a `BEGIN` and and `END`

```
IF condition1
BEGIN
    -- Do stuff
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    IF condition2
    BEGIN
        -- Do Stuff
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF condition3
        BEGIN
            -- Do stuff
        END
    END
END
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx#Examples (Example D)

The `END$$` should be `END`

Comment: Still getting these errors:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'REGEXP'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 42
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 42
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 44
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: Its down to 4 errors.Please help:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 42
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure fn_phonenumber, Line 45
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_bhagyashreed_phonenumber(@input VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @compare VARCHAR(30) = ''
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 1
    DECLARE @varout VARCHAR(30) = ''
    DECLARE @val VARCHAR(30) = ''
    DECLARE @Phoutput VARCHAR(50) = ''
    DECLARE @var INT

    SET @var = LEN(@input)

    IF @var <> 10
        OR @input LIKE '%[^a-z0-9-'']%'
      SET @Phoutput = 'Invalid Format'
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        WHILE @cnt <= 10
          BEGIN
            SET @compare = SUBSTRING(@input, @cnt, 1)
            SET @val=CASE
                       WHEN @compare IN ('a', 'b', 'c', '2') THEN 2
                       WHEN @compare IN ('d', 'e', 'f', '3') THEN 3
                       WHEN @compare IN ('g', 'h', 'i', '4') THEN 4
                       WHEN @compare IN ('j', 'k', 'l', '5') THEN 5
                       WHEN @compare IN ('m', 'n', 'o', '6') THEN 6
                       WHEN @compare IN ('p', 'q', 'r', 's', '7') THEN 7
                       WHEN @compare IN ('t', 'u', 'v', '8') THEN 8
                       WHEN @compare IN ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '9') THEN 9
                       WHEN @compare IN ('1') THEN 1
                       WHEN @compare IN ('0') THEN 0
                       ELSE 0
                     END
            SET @varout = CONCAT(@varout, @val)
            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
          END
      END

    IF @Phoutput <> 'Invalid Format'
      BEGIN
        SET @Phoutput = CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING(@varout, 1, 3), ')', ' ', SUBSTRING(@varout, 4, 3), '-', SUBSTRING(@varout, 7, 4))
      END

    RETURN @Phoutput
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to be different.
Try this with other sample data also.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,phoneString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('7589586586'),('758ABC6586'),('758ABC65')

;With CTE as
(
select id,replace(phoneString,char(97),'2') phoneString,97 rn 
from @tbl where phoneString like '%[Aa-Zz]%' and len(phoneString)=10

union all

select id, replace(phoneString,char(rn)
,case when rn BETWEEN 97 and 99 then '2' 
when rn BETWEEN 100 and 102 then '3' 
when rn BETWEEN 103 and 105 then '4' 
when rn BETWEEN 106 and 108 then '5' 
when rn BETWEEN 109 and 111 then '6' 
when rn BETWEEN 112 and 114 then '7' 
when rn BETWEEN 115 and 117 then '8' 
when rn BETWEEN 119 and 122 then '9' 
else 'X' end),rn+1 from cte c
where rn<122 and phoneString like '%[Aa-Zz]%'

)
,CTE1 as
(
select  *,ROW_NUMBER()over( partition by id order by rn desc) rn1 
from cte    
)

select id,phonestring,'('+SUBSTRING(phonestring,1,3)+' ) '+ 
SUBSTRING(phonestring,4,3)+'-'+SUBSTRING(phonestring,8,3)
 Validated from cte1
where rn1=1
union ALL
select id,phonestring,'('+SUBSTRING(phonestring,1,3)+' ) '+ 
SUBSTRING(phonestring,4,3)+'-'+SUBSTRING(phonestring,8,3)
 Validated from @tbl
where isnumeric(phoneString)=1 and len(phoneString)=10
union ALL
select id,phonestring,'invalid format' from @tbl 
where len(phonestring)<10
```